# Новый массив из старого (DOM)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть псевдомассив элементов со страницы, храниться в переменной.

Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на каждый элемент к нему присваивался класс active, но с одним условием: что при нажатии на рандомный элемент из этого массива к нему присваивался класс active, после этого, если нажать на ещё один элемент (рандомный), то к нему тоже присваивался класс active, но если нажать на третий, рандомный опять же, элемент то у первого нажатого убирался класс active, но у второго и третьего оставался и так далее.

Надеюсь понятно изъяснил, нуждаюсь в помощи как сделать такую логику, хотя бы русскими словами что использовать.

Comment: приведите существующий код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
~function (els) {
  var active = []
  
  for (var x of els) {
    x.addEventListener('click', handler)
  }
  
  function handler(event) {
    if (!this.classList.contains('active')) {
      this.classList.add('active')

      if (active.push(this) == 3) {
        active[0].classList.remove('active')
        active.shift()
      }
    }
  }
}(document.querySelectorAll('button'))
```

```css
html { counter-reset: i; }
button::before { counter-increment: i; content: counter(i); }
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<button></button>
<button></button>
<button></button>
<button></button>
<button></button>
<button></button>
<button></button>
<button></button>
<button></button>
```